# Will my app get rejected for using CATRANSITION pageCurl?

Tags: iphone, calayer, catransition

Hello was just wondering if my app will get rejected using the following code:

```
[animation setDuration:1.0];
    [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    animation.type = @"pageUnCurl";
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.startProgress = 0.78;
    animation.endProgress = 1.
```

0;

This is using the undocumented page curl function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the function is not documented by Apple, it will...

Comment: Hmm okay thanks because I cannot see any warnings in the IDE.

Comment: Has anyone tried using the above code and was ur app rejected?